# Google Cloud SQL with non-Google hosted website

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a web app that I have built and am hosting with my own provider. I am wanting to connect this to a Google Cloud SQL database. What is the best way to do this?

I spoke with my hosting provider and they stated that they have no IP addresses / ranges they can give me to setup with GCSQL.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Sorry if this questions is completely simple and not complicated at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect using the instance IP address provided by Google Cloud SQL ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip)). Be sure to use SSL.